# Graphs using pgfplots: Failure when using x as a negative power

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I'm trying to plot the decharging curve of a capacitor. The code is as follows:

```
  \documentclass{article}      
  \usepackage{pgfplots}      
  \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain = -360:360, samples=40,
    width=.6\linewidth, height=7cm, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0]

    \addplot[color=blue] {100 * 2.7^(-x/0.0001)};

    \end{axis}      
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In fact, there are two issues. First up, there is an internal error which is probably caused by the division by `0.0001`. The compilation seems to take forever.

But even if you omit the division and only raise to the power of `-x`, there is a problem. It says:

```
Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide 97.26378000000000 by 0.0, but I cannot divide any number by 0.0.
```

A second error below simply says `Arithmetic overflow`.

Does anyone know what are the issues here and how to solve them? Any workarounds?

Comment: I think it might be because x=0 is one sample at which the function is evaluated.

Comment: I would guess that if you omit the division, `2.7^360` causes an Arithmetic overflow - the number is just too big to deal with.  I would recommend figuring out what `ymax` you really want.

Comment: @nidhin While that's true, I don't understand how that should be an issue. Raising any number to the power of 0 should evaluate to 1. Though apart from that, the problem persists anyway if I set xmin=1

Comment: @R.Hahnemann My bad. It should not matter. But hanging samples=41 works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `xmin=0` and `xmax=10`, you can change the domain also that range. Otherwise 2.7^(360/0.0001) will cause overflow. Reducing the domain will work.

*Since the capacitor is discharging exponentially with a time constant `0.0001`, 
The samples should also be spaced in the same range. Hence number of samples required to get a good plot in the range 0:10 will be high. It is better to restrict the domain to a smaller value. I used 0:0.01.*

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain = 0:0.01, samples=40,
%    width=.6\linewidth, height=7cm, xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ]
    \addplot[color=blue] {100 * 2.7^(-x/0.0001)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]